# Problema al subir imagen Laravel 7 ruta .tmp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

buenas tengo un problema al intentar guardar la ruta de la imagen que subo en la base de datos, la imagen si se almacena bien en la carpeta storage, pero la URL en la base de datos no, lo que almacena es una ruta temporal como por ejemplo **C:\Users\Francisco\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAB7A.tmp**.

mi controlador de guardar es el siguiente

```
   public function guardar(Request $request)
{
     if ($foto = Mascota::setFotoMasctota($request->foto)) 
         $request->request->add(['foto'=> $foto]);
       
        Mascota::create($request->all()); 
    return redirect('mascota/index')->with('mensaje','Registro creado');
}
```

la función setFotoMascota es la siguiente:

```
    public static function setFotoMascota($foto, $actual = false)
{
  
    if ($foto) {
        if ($actual) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete("imagenes/mascotas/$actual");
        }
        $imageName = Str::random(20) . '.jpg';
        $imagen = Image::make($foto)->encode('jpg', 75);
        $imagen->resize(530, 470, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        Storage::disk('public')->put("imagenes/mascotas/$imageName", $imagen->stream());
        return $imageName;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

al hacer un dd(request->all());
obtengo la siguiente informacion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

podrían indicarme porque no esta almacenando la URL correcta en la base de dato que deberia ser **/imagenes/mascota/nombre_archivo** ?

Comment: intenta haciendo un `$data = $request->all(); $data['foto'] = $foto;` porque estas agregando al request no cambiando, otra opcion seria rellenar los campos manuales. y no pasar el `$reques->all()` directamente! en todo caso deberias solo guardar el nombre de la imagen y no la ruta en la base de datos ya que e de imaginar que la ruta es estatica y lo unico dinamico es el nombre de las imagenes!

Comment: @Bryro de la primera forma que indicas me da el mismo resultado, haciéndolo manualmente si me sirve pero ahí no utilizaría el metodo setFotoMascota solo le inserto la ruta de esta forma **$foto->store('imagenes/mascotas','public')**, sobre solo pasarle el nombre podrias ser tan amable de enseñarme como hacerlo. soy nuevo y en realidad estoy aprendiendo a utilizar laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
 $imageName = Str::random(20) . '.jpg';
 // evita nombres de imagenes duplicadas opcional
 $imageName = uniqid().time() . '.jpg';
 $thumbnailPath = public_path("imagenes/mascotas");
 $thumb_img = \Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(530, 470 function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->upsize();
    });
 // utilizamos el metodo save de la clase Image.
 $thumb_img->save($thumbnailPath.'/'.$imagename,100);
 return $imageName;
```

la llamda a la funcion seria mejor pasandole como parametro:

```
// enviar unicamente el file
$request->file('foto');
```

guardar solo parametros especificos:

```
$Mascota=  new Mascota();
$Mascota->pictures = $foto;
// resto del codigo
$Mascota->save();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias asi funciona perfecto, ahora tengo otro problema al tratar de ver la imagen  me sale en la inspeccion error 403, ya hice **php artisan storage:link** y  le estoy pasando la URL por medio de storage::url pero el problema es de permisos y ha le di full permisos a la carpeta storage y a la carpeta simbolica

Comment: perfecto me alegra mucho que te funcionara! para ello es la comunidad. saludos!